# How to find owner of a shared calendar in appointment and meeting window?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

There is no field in the appointment Item or the meeting item that determines the current calendar which i am accessing is shared calendar or my own calendar folder?

How do i get this? Is there is a way in outlook object model to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `meetingItem.Parent.StoreId` (not the AppointmentItem, I believe). What you get then is a HexId string that, if converted to a plain text string, contains the MS Exchange account name after `/cn=` (I think at the end of the string).

With that name, you can do a `CreateRecipient(thatName)` and `Outlook.Recipient.Resolve()` it. 
After that, you can access the name of the account by using recipient.Name

Sorry, I tried to paste code in this answer, but it didn't work as expected and took too long. Please ask if you need more directions.